# CSS Link parameter Day older then today - 1month?

Tags: html, css

This work good:

HTML:

```
<li>
<a name=something href="http://.../.  .html">Something</a>
</li>
```

CSS: If name="Something" then link backroundcolor=yellow

```
a[name="something"] {
background: #ffff00;
}
```

How to get this to work?

HTML:

```
<li>
<a date=3.10.2014 href="http://.../.  .html">Something  OLD</a>
</li>
```

CSS: If date older then today-1month then backroundcolor=red

```
a[date<"4.10.2014"] {
background: red;
}
```

Comment: You will need to store the date on some data attribute and make the  calcs with JS ... CSS can't do that

Comment: Are these flat HTML files you are coding or are they coming from some server side code? If you're doing something server side, add `class="old"` to your `a` with the appropriate business logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be done with css only. You can use javascript to iterate over all `a`s though and add a class if your criteria matches.

```
links = document.getElementsByTagName("a")
var oneMonthAgo = new Date();
oneMonthAgo.setMonth(oneMonthAgo.getMonth() -1);

for (var i=0; i<links.length;i++){
    console.log(links[i].dataset.date);
    var date = new Date(links[i].dataset.date);
    if (date < oneMonthAgo){
        links[i].className = links[i].className + 'old'
    }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8trL8x8n/1/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the dates will be in this `4.11.2014` format this is how you can do it.

#### HTML:

```
<li>
    <a data-date="4.11.2014" href="http://.../.  .html">Something  OLD</a>
</li>
```

#### JavaScript:

```
var lis = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
var newDate = newDate().getMonth() + 1;

for (i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
    var oldDate = lis[i].getAttribute('data[date]').split('.')[1];
    if ((oldDate == 11 && newDate < 11) || oldDate > newDate) {
        lis[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    }
}
```